# There was an error loading payments.Please refresh or try again later. PWA Venia Theme Magento2.4 issue coming on

Tags: pwa, magento2.4.1, venia

[image]I have installed PWA Venia Theme with magento2.4.1 EE but on checkout, no payment methods are loading.
Error Getting: **There was an error loading payments. Please refresh or try again later.**
Attached the image below Is anyone faced the same issue? or anyone has any information regarding this issue?

Answer (score 4):

For me, this issue was caused by missing any valid payment methods. As indicated by the error message, I followed the error to [checkoutPage.js line 180](https://github.com/magento/pwa-studio/blob/718e527c03e1088cb5a01409401487c3bcda3b84/packages/venia-ui/lib/components/CheckoutPage/checkoutPage.js#L181) and debugging showed **paymentMethods** (which is the dynamic build-time content of [paymentMethodCollection.js](https://github.com/magento/pwa-studio/blob/718e527c03e1088cb5a01409401487c3bcda3b84/packages/venia-ui/lib/components/CheckoutPage/PaymentInformation/paymentMethodCollection.js)) was empty.

After adding the correct [Braintree sandbox credentials](https://www.braintreepayments.com/sandbox) to Stores -> Configuration -> Sales -> Payment Methods -> Recommended solutions -> Braintree, the error was gone.

For Magento 2.4.2 and PWA Studio 10.0.0 (compatibility [here](https://magento.github.io/pwa-studio/technologies/magento-compatibility/)), if you add the checkmo [extension](https://github.com/magento/pwa-studio/tree/develop/packages/extensions/venia-sample-payments-checkmo) (mentioned in the release notes [here](https://github.com/magento/pwa-studio/releases/tag/v10.0.0)), the **Check / Money Order** option also appears.

[image: valid payment options]

**TLDR**: Check if you have valid payment options for PWA.

Answer (score 0):

Hi I am using Braintree payment method in PWA venia theme magento 2.4 but not get successful order and showing this error  "unable to place order.your payment could not be token please try again or use a different payment method.unknown or expired payment_method_nance."